# .net timer that does not run if previous invocation has not completed

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I have a program that needs to do something every 60 seconds.  Almost always this takes 1-2 seconds to complete but there is a condition whereby it could take a few minutes.

Does anybody know of a .net timer that will not invoke the "time elapsed" method if the previous invocation has not yet completed?

I could obviously do this with a check like this...

if(beingRun){

}

Comment: If the previous invocation hasn't finished, do you still want to run the current invocation (as soon as the previous has finished) or skip it altogther?

Comment: Why don't you just write a simple program and find out for yourself?  It's pretty trivial to write a test program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Enabled` property.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static readonly Timer MyTimer = new Timer()
        {
            Interval = 60,
        };

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyTimer.Elapsed += MyTimerOnElapsed;
        }

        private static void MyTimerOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs)
        {
            MyTimer.Enabled = false;

            try
            {
                // Some code here
            }
            finally
            {
                MyTimer.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write an `async` method to do this:

```
public async void Recur(Action action, TimeSpan time, CancellationToken token)
{
    while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        action();
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(time, token);
        }
        catch(TaskCancelledException)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
Recur(() => DoMyBigJob(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), cts.Token);
```

and to kill it

```
cts.Token.Cancel();
```

Don't lose your CancellationTokenSource, otherwise you'll have a rogue async loop that's out of your control.

Answer (score 0):

I normally just store whether or not the timer should process in a bool, like so:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60).TotalMiliseconds;

bool processingSomething = false;

void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!processingSomething)
    {
        processingSomething = true;

        // Process stuff here . . .

        processingSomething = false;
    }
}
```